# How can i set the image so that when i open the keyboard it does not rescale?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I have set the image in background, when i open the keyboard the image gets squeezed from the top.
I also don't want my EditText field to move to the top.

Comment: I want exactly the opposite, so I'll have to watch this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your activity's layout will be resized when the virtual keyboard is shown. This can cause views positioned within the activity to shift around. The specific behavior is determined by the layout you're using and the layout parameters you've set.

To keep your layout the same size when the virtual keyboard is shown, set the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute to `adjustPan` in the activity definition in AndroidManifest.xml. Here's an example activity:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/my_activity_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

You can read more about the other flags that can be set here in the [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) documentation for this.